# FragmentActivity being used in place of getActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

This is a strange question, but the `getActivity()` call in the LogCat is showing up as `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`, making it return a null object reference...

This is the code that throws the exception...

```
public void updateTimerLabel()
{
    Thread duration = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    timerFooter.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    duration.start();
}
```

And here is the LogCat entry...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at testapplication.fragments.FragmentA$6.run(FragmentA.java:442)
```

As you can see, i called `getActivity()` and there is no mention of `FragmentActivity` throughout the entirety of my code. Any solutions?

Comment: `getActivity()` is most likely returning null because your Fragment hasn't been attached yet.

Comment: The reason for crash is that your Thread gets started when the activity containing your fragment(in which you started the thread) has been destroyed. You need to check `if(getActivity != null)` before using `runOnUiThread`.

Comment: Agree with above comments. You also can call isAdded() in fragment to check fragment been attached

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. How would i attach the `Fragment` to the `Activity`?